# draw with alpha 0 and keep rgb color in LIBGDX

Tags: opengl, colors, libgdx, alpha

I want to draw some textures into a fbo, some with alpha 0 and other with alpha 1 so I can use the alpha channel to store info for my shader.
I'm using this code for each texture I want with the alpha 0 rendered in the fbo

```
batch.begin();   
batch.setColor(new Color(1,1,1,0));
batch.draw(texture,x,y);
batch.setColor(new Color(1,1,1,1));
batch.end();
```

The problem is that when I try to get the rgb color in my shader I only get black. It is like when I set alpha 0 tint it zeroes the other channels.

What Im doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

one easy way to do it

```
Sprite s=new Sprite(tex);
float alpha=0.5f; //or whatever you want
s.draw(batch,alpha); render the sprite with the given alpha without effecting other images
```

Here you will set the alpha value for that particular sprite only, while if you use

```
batch.setColor(new Color(1,1,1,0));
```

In this case, you set the value for the entire batch cycle and u have to change it again and can be tedious if u have the differnt alpha requirement for different sprites.

Comment: I get the same result as with batch.setColor(new Color(1,1,1,0));